# Update an array of text with itself to run a "trigger" function in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search, psql

Full-text search in PostgreSQL is new to me. So bear with me. I'm working on an *existing* PostgreSQL table that has a column of type `text[]` (named `tags`) that I'd like to implement full-text search on. I've added another column of type `ts_vector` (named `tags_tsv`) that will contain the indexable lexemes from the `tags` column. I also have an index on `tags` and a trigger to update `tags_tsv` any time there are updates or inserts applied to `tags`.

In order to update the existing rows in this table, I need to run this trigger by updating the `tags` column with itself. I ran `update tableName set tags = tags;` but get the error `ERROR:  column "tags" is not of a character type`.

Okay. To get the `tags` array into text I figured I need to use `array_to_string` like so `update tableName set tags = array_to_string(tags, ',');` but I get `You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.`.

I'm lost. What am I missing?

I'm doing all this work in `psql` and below is the table definition:

```
Column    |   Type   |
----------+----------|
id        | integer  |
title     | text     |
tags      | text[]   |
title_tsv | tsvector |
tags_tsv  | tsvector |

Indexes:
  "test_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
  "title_idx" gin (title_tsv)
  "tags_idx" gin (tags_tsv)

Triggers:
  tsvectorupdate BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON test FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE tsvector_update_trigger('title_tsv', 'pg_catalog.english', 'title')
  tsvectorupdate2 BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON test FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE tsvector_update_trigger('tags_tsv', 'pg_catalog.english', 'tags')
```

Comment: Upvote for "bare with me".

Comment: You should show your table definition and trigger. There is probably a bug there. In principle, your technique ahould work, but it may be a good idea to `VACUUM (FULL)` afterwards.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I've updated it. Oh and changed "bare" to "bear" lol.

Comment: You've delivered almost complete info. Almost makes a difference as a bug is still hidden in the trigger function.